# How to change the icon of an Android app in Eclipse?

Tags: android, eclipse, android-icons, application-icon

I am developing an app using Eclipse IDE Juno and Android SDK.

How do I change my app's icon?

Answer (score 324, accepted):

Go into your **AndroidManifest.xml** file

- Click on the Application Tab
- Find the Text Box Labelled "Icon"
- Then click the "Browse" button at the end of the text box
- Click    the Button Labelled: "Create New Icon..."
- Create your icon
- Click Finish
- Click "Yes to All" if you already have the icon set to something
  else.

Enjoy using a gui rather then messing with an image editor!

Comment: Worth mentioning that you need to open the `AndroidManifest.xml` by Android Manifest Editor - by right click on the file in Package Explorer.

Comment: Note: Have to do a clean before you build after changing the icon.

Answer (score 43):

In your **AndroidManifest.xml** file

```
<application
        android:name="ApplicationClass"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"  <--------
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
```

Answer (score 22):

***Icon creation wizard***

- Select your project
- Ctrl+n
- Android Icon Set

Comment: Or... right-click project->New->Other->Android Icon Set.  For macintosh computers, the shortcut is command+n.

Answer (score 6):

Look for this on your **Manifest.xml** `android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"` then change the `ic_launcher` to the name of your icon which is on your `@drawable` folder.

Answer (score 4):

You can find an easy guide [here](http://envyandroid.com/archives/301/change-the-android-app-icon)

The step are 2:
 - Copy the icon in the correct folder/folders
 - Change the AndroidManifest.xml

Answer (score 2):

Rob R.'s answer was definitely the way to go. I tried copying the ic_launcher.png files from another project and Eclipse still wouldn't read them. Going through the manifest is much quicker and easier.