# How to name application and give it an icon?

Tags: java, eclipse, macos, tags, icons

I'm working in eclipse and I have made an application without name and icon. When i start the application it's a really creepy name displaying in the upper left corner (Mac). It's some thing like. I wonder how I can change this to my own name. Second question is how i can change the icon. Can I do that in eclipse?

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of exactly what you're talking about? Are you talking about the icon of a JFrame? The icon of a jar? Something else?

Comment: the icon of the application, or .jar. I could not upload a picture for some reason.

Comment: Basically, you can create a application bundle, as described. [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jweb/packagingAppsForMac.html), or, if you can find some documentation, use the com.apple.eawt.Application API. But the documentation is VERY light...

Answer (score 0):

If you're using JFrames, you can try setting the icon image as follows.

```
frame.setIconImage(img);
```

Also, by name it sounds a bit like you mean the frame's title.  When you create the a frame, you can set the title as follows:

```
Frame frame = new JFrame("Title goes here");
```

Comment: no... when I have exported it and start it it have a crazy name.

Answer (score 0):

To change name: [How to change an Android app's name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5443304/how-to-change-an-android-apps-name)

To change icon: [How to change the icon of an Android app in Eclipse?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11737932/change-app-icon-in-eclipse-ide-with-android-sdk)

It's already here at stackoverflow, please check if your answers are here before posting.

Comment: Stupid question...how is this related?

Answer (score 0):

The prefered method would be to create a [Mac OS application bundle](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jweb/packagingAppsForMac.html) (and the [bundler](https://java.net/projects/appbundler)), but if this seems like to much work, you can supply custom properties to, for example, you could supply the `Xdock:name` property when running the application, for example...

```
-DXdock:name="Application Name"
```

If you can't do that, you can set it when your application runs, for example...

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        // Sets the application name on the menu bar
        System.setProperty("Xdock:name", "Application Name");

        // Set the applications dock icon...
        Application application = Application.getApplication();            
        application.setDockIconImage(ImageIO.read(TestDockIcon.class.getResource("/Icon.png")));

        // Start the application...
        new TestDockIcon();
    } catch (IOException exp) {
        exp.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```