# I want to make my java program have an icon in the Taskbar for Windows and the Dock for Mac

Tags: java, windows, macos, swing, icons

I have a program that I made for my Spanish teacher and I want to make the dock/taskbar have an icon. I have an attempt here, but it doesn't work.

```
package com.jaketherey;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.net.URL;

import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class Inglés_Switcher {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {

        JFrame frame = new switcherContent();

        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setSize(950, 850);
        frame.setResizable(false);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setTitle("Inglés Switcher by Jacob Batista");
        frame.getContentPane().setBackground(Color.GREEN);

        //Attempt to Add Icon, Remember I want it for both Mac and Windows

        ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon("/com/jaketherey/ñ.png");
        frame.setIconImage(icon.getImage());

        }

    });

}

}
```

If you need the JFrame it uses for the content then I will give it to you but I didn't think it was important for the problem...

Help? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For Windows, start by taking a look at [`Window#setIconImages`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Window.html#setIconImages(java.util.List)), demonstrated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19825481/setting-an-icon-for-my-java-application/19825494#19825494)

For MacOS, it becomes a little more difficult.  You need to make use of a custom library (available only on the Mac)

Apple `eAWT` provides the `Application` class that allows to change the dock icon of an application.

```
import com.apple.eawt.Application;
...
Application application = Application.getApplication();
Image image = ...
application.setDockIconImage(image);
```

Also demonstrated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20980483/how-to-name-application-and-give-it-an-icon/20981700#20981700)

As stated in the example linked above, the preferred method for depleying on MacOS would be to make use of the [Mac OS application bundler](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jweb/packagingAppsForMac.html)