# Drawable-ldpi icon is missing

Tags: android, eclipse, android-icons, application-icon

I have created an icons in Eclipse using the steps on accepted answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11737932/change-app-icon-in-eclipse-ide-with-android-sdk)

But looks like `drawable-ldpi is missing`, is that fine? Please someone can explain why it does not have an icon? OR Should I need to manually add it there?

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You don't need it, any ldpi device will just scale the mdpi image. ldpi devices are becoming more and more uncommon, currently sitting at [<s>8.1%</s> 2.9%](http://developer.android.com/about/dashboards/index.html). The developers at google (sorry I don't have a link, it was a video) recommend that you don't need resources smaller than mdpi.

Comment: For your references I just found that resource: "Android also supports low-density (LDPI) screens, but you normally don't need to create custom assets at this size because Android effectively down-scales your HDPI assets by 1/2 to match the expected size."  http://developer.android.com/design/style/iconography.html

Comment: But can we safely delete the drawable-ldpi, if it's empty and we don't use it?

Comment: Yes you can, there are many possible combinations of resource folders and their qualifiers and they are all optional.